# PHP - Most efficient way to check array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a large array of objects which I need to efficiently check:

1. If a property exists within the object
2. To get the value

A simplified version of data structure would look like:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1222
            [name] => Foo
            [pass] => stdClass Object
                      (
                          [ID] => 1234
                          [type] => Foo
                      )
         )

[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2333
            [name] => Bar
            [pass] => stdClass Object
                      (
                          [ID] => 4567
                          [type] => Foo
                          [flag] =>  1
                      )
        )
```

Let's say we need to check if 'flag' exists and get the value.

I'm currently achieving what I need by iterating through the structure using a foreach loop, but I'm looking to make efficiencies.

Comment: `foreach` loop with `break` statement would be enough

Comment: Do you know the path, meaning you know that `flag` would be under `pass`?

Comment: `foreach` loops are pretty efficient. What types of issues are you running into with the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Yes I know the path to flag, although flag may not always exist.

Comment: No issues, just that the data structure is so large. At times I'm looping through multiple large data structures. I'm just trying posing the question for efficiency savings.

Comment: The only optimization you could really make is to partition the data as you build the structure, rather than building it and then attempting to filter/sort - any time you've got a collection of un-ordered data and you want to know if some property is true of each element, you can't be more efficient than linearly scanning the data.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot It seems your final comment is the only chance of this question receiving an answer.  Please repost your comment as an answer, so that: Sam can choose to mark it as the accepted answer, future readers can learn from your advice without reading through all of the comments, and so this question can appear resolved.